# WebSocket not connecting |. Django Channels | WebSocket

Tags: python-3.x, django, websocket, django-celery, django-channels

I am using the `WebsocketConsumer` consumer and when I disconnect the websocket connection it gives the below error.
Also when I have already one open connection and when I try to create a connection with the same route it gets Disconnected and gives the same

```
Application instance <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<StaticFilesWrapper.__call__() running at /Volumes/Data/Projects/LocoNav-LM/vt-lm-server/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py:44> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/futures.py:360, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x1076a2580>()]>> for connection <WebSocketProtocol client=['127.0.0.1', 54789] path=b'/ws/users/'> took too long to shut down and was killed.
```

My code:-

```
class TestMultipleUsers(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        logging.info('connecting....')
        self.accept()
        redis_client = RedisClient(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
        redis_client.subscribe_and_listen()
        redis_client.subscribe_channel('test')
        for message in redis_client.sub.listen():
            if message is not None and isinstance(message, dict):
                print(message)
                self.send(text_data="1")
    
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        logging.info('disconnecting....')
        logging.info(close_code)
```

However, whenever I disconnect the web socket from Postman the disconnect method never gets called.

requirements.txt

```
channels==3.0.4
Django==4.0
celery==5.2.3
```

Here are my Logs:-

```
2022-02-27 20:28:06 Process: 21283 Thread: 123145371021312 [INFO    ] HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2022-02-27 20:28:06 Process: 21283 Thread: 123145371021312 [INFO    ] Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2022-02-27 20:28:06 Process: 21283 Thread: 123145371021312 [INFO    ] Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/users/ [127.0.0.1:60683]
2022-02-27 20:28:09 Process: 21283 Thread: 123145371021312 [INFO    ] WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/users/ [127.0.0.1:60683]
2022-02-27 20:28:09 Process: 21283 Thread: 123145387810816 [INFO    ] connecting....
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/users/ [127.0.0.1:60683]
2022-02-27 20:28:09 Process: 21283 Thread: 123145371021312 [INFO    ] WebSocket CONNECT /ws/users/ [127.0.0.1:60683]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/users/ [127.0.0.1:60685]
2022-02-27 20:28:12 Process: 21283 Thread: 123145371021312 [INFO    ] WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/users/ [127.0.0.1:60685]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/users/ [127.0.0.1:60685]
2022-02-27 20:28:17 Process: 21283 Thread: 123145371021312 [INFO    ] WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/users/ [127.0.0.1:60685]
2022-02-27 20:28:28 Process: 21283 Thread: 123145371021312 [WARNING ] Application instance <Task pending name='Task-7' coro=<StaticFilesWrapper.__call__() running at /Volumes/Data/Projects/LocoNav-LM/vt-lm-server/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py:44> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/futures.py:360, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x10f495940>()]>> for connection <WebSocketProtocol client=['127.0.0.1', 60685] path=b'/ws/users/'> took too long to shut down and was killed.
```

Comment: can you get out the  redis_client  from your class init? because you open a new connection per user

Comment: Yes, I am opening a new connection per user, so how removing the redis_client form connect will help? @Nova

Comment: this error is because you wait a long time in your connect method and when you don't pass any handshake you get that, so for testing propose to try t comment Redis process from your connect method @Subham

Comment: @Nova I removed but it didn't help. I have added some logs though.

Comment: add raise StopConsumer() to your overwritted disconnect method